# How to send RawTransaction to Quorum blockchain

Tags: web3js, quorum

May I know how can I send a RawTransaction to Quorum blockchain? Can I just use the send rawTransaction method that I used in Ethereum and web3 and just to set the gasPrice to 0? Will it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the Quorum sendRawTransaction() method will work the same as in Ethereum.
You just need to set the price to zero.

Note that if you are using web3 v1.0 or later, that method has been renamed to sendSignedTransaction().

Comment: Thank you for replying my question. Quick one, I managed to send transactions to Quorum network but when I checked on the blockchain explorer the events was empty. Does it means the function didn't execute completely?

Comment: I'm not sure what the explorer you are using displays, in terms of events.
If the transaction did not return a transaction hash and the transaction is not sitting in the transaction pool then my guess would be that it didn't get successfully executed.
If you can examine the log file on the quorum node where you submitted the transaction, then you should be able to tell whether it failed (and why).